# Filter columns by values in a row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multilevel-analysis

I have obtained the statistics for my dataframe by df.describe() in Pandas.

```
statistics = df.describe()
```

I want to filter the statistics dataframe base on count:

```
    main    Meas1     Meas2 Meas3   Meas4  Meas5
    sublvl  Value     Value Value   Value   Value       
    count   7.000000  1.0   1.0     582.00  97.000000       
    mean    30        37.0  26.0    33.03   16.635350
```

I want to get something like that:
filter out all Values with count less than 30 and show me only the columns with count >30 in a new dataframe (or give me a list with all main that have count>30).

For the above example, I want:

```
    main       Meas4    Meas5
    sublvl     Value    Value       
    count      582.00   97.000000       
    mean       33.03    16.635350
```

and `[Meas4, Meas5]`

I have tried

```
thresh = statistics.columns[statistics['count']>30]
```

And variations thereof.

Comment: `df[df.columns[(df['count'] > 30).values]]` should work. If not, please provide some code to reproduce exactly the dataframe you have.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ this throws a KeyError. The dataframe I have is made by df.describe() from a two level df with first level Meas1,2,3 etc. and second level "Value"

Comment: And what is the index?

Comment: The standard describe() index:: {count, mean, std...} etc

Comment: `[column for column in statistics.columns if statistics.loc['count'][column] > 3]` This is from the answer i have shared. I tried it and it works. please check.

Comment: @VikashSingh how can I get only the first level of the multilevel in the list? so from my example only Meas1, Meas2, without the Value subindex?

Comment: you can simply do this `[column[0] for column in statistics.columns if statistics.loc['count'][column] > 3]`. this will chose the first level of the column.

Comment: @Moiraine24 Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name':[1,2,3,4,5], 'val':[1, None,None,None,None]})

df

name    val
0   1   1.0
1   2   NaN
2   3   NaN
3   4   NaN
4   5   NaN
```

if you want to use `describe()` then note that describe does not give all columns. only columns with numerical data types are returned by default:

you can do so in this way:

```
statistics = df.describe()

# to describe all columns you can do this
statistics = df.describe(include = 'all')

[column for column in statistics.columns if statistics.loc['count'][column] > 3]
# output ['name']
```

As discussed in comments, As this is a MultiIndex column to chose only first index we can do this:

```
# [column[0] for column in statistics.columns if statistics.loc['count'][column] > 3] # this code won't work correctly for non multi index dataframes.
```

for each column check if count is > threshold and add it to chosen_columns list:

```
chosen_columns = []
for column in df.columns:
    if len(df[column].value_counts()) > 3:
        chosen_columns.append(column)

# chosen_columns output: ['name']
```

OR:

```
chosen_columns = []
for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].count() > 3:
        chosen_columns.append(column)

# chosen_columns output: ['name']
```

Comment: I want to use the resulting statistics dataframe (it actually plays in my favor that statistics uses only numerical value columns) and perform the filter on it.

Comment: @Moiraine24 not a problem. I have added answer for all the options.

Comment: This list however gives me both indeces as tuples,[('Meas1', 'Value'),
 ('Meas2', 'Value'),
 ('Meas3', 'Value'),...

Comment: @Moiraine24 you can use a simple list comprehension to filter the 'Meas's out. `[v[0] for v in values]`. Can you share your original dataframe so I can figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting value by column is much more easy in pandas, so you can do transpose first, select as you wishes, and transpose back.

```
statistics.T[statistics.T['count']>30].T
```